# Regex groups for dash delimited filename in URL

Tags: regex

I have a URL that is structured like so: `<domain>/<subdirectory>/<filename>-<semantic_version>-<hash>.<filetype>`
For example, it could look like: `https://cdn.example.com/sample_files/some_file-1.2.3-56857cfc709d3996f057252c16ec4656f5292802.css`

So far I have the following regex which gives me the entire filename. However, I'd like to individually get the `filename`, `semantic_version`, and `hash` as defined above. You can assume that the `filename` will not has dashes in the name.

`([^/\\&\?]+)$(?<=(?:.js))`

Comment: Try `^http\S+\/(\w+)-(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)-([0-9a-f]+)\.\w+$` https://regex101.com/r/F1X8io/1 or change `\w+` into a specific file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the protocol and then until the last forward slash.

After that, capture 1+ word chars in group 1 for the file name, a repeating part in group 2 to capture digits divided by dots and in the third group a character class which would match all the characters in the hash.

```
^http\S+\/(\w+)-(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)-([0-9a-f]+)\.\w+$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `http\S+\/` Match the protocol followed by 1+ non whitespace chars, then backtrack till the last `/`
- `(\w+)-` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars followed by `-`
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)-` Capture **group 2**, match digits divided by dots followed by `-`
- `([0-9a-f]+)\.\w+` Capture **group 3**, match 1+ times the chars from the hash followed by `.` and 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F1X8io/1/)

If the hash always has 40 characters, you could match `[a-z0-9]{40}` instead of `[a-z]+` to be a bit more precise.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple capture groups that don't match `-` characters.

```
([^-/\\&\?]+)-([^-/\\&\?]+)-([^-/\\&\?]+)\.[a-z]+$(?<=(?:.js))
```

Comment: Hi, after much searching, your regex captures exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.  But this will be in a rewrite rule in .htaccess, and I only want it to apply to files in a particular folder.  How do I do that?  For example:
https://example.com/journal/erv-1976-22333-15222.php
the rule should only run for files in the "journal" directory. How?  Currently I have
/([^-\/\\&\?]+)-([^-\/\\&\?]+)-([^-\/\\&\?]+)\.[a-z]+$(?<=(?:.php))/gm

Comment: Put the directory at the beginning of the regexp.

Comment: `journal/([^-/\\&\?]+)-([^-/\\&\?]+)-([^-/\\&\?]+)\.[a-z]+$(?<=(?:.js))`